# Whats the url that displays all posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I simply want a link to my blog archives.  They are just normal posts, but I cannot seem to find the right url for them to add to my menu.

Comment: why you marking me down?  It's a simple, straightforward question.

Comment: http://davidspeightphotography.co.uk/wordpress

Comment: are all your posts in the category of "uncategorized"?

Comment: yes, ahh do they need to have a category?  I thought there would be a way to show them all, like you can with custom posts

Comment: yeah every post has to have a category. usually i'll create a category called "blog" (just renamed uncategorized) and install the Yoast SEO plugin and remove the /category/ from the URL

Comment: ah that means I'll have to choose a category every time.  Thats a bit rubbish.  Thanks for the tip I'll try that.

Comment: They don't HAVE to have a category, but it's certainly best to do. This will help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30037/default-archive-url-wordpress

Answer (score 17):

right url for them to add to my menu.

http://yourwebsite.com/?post_type=post

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to necessarily use a category to every post.

Actually the file to list all posts of any category and date is the index.php. You just write 'the loop' as told on codex.

So if you changed your index.php to make it as a fancy page and not the post list only, now you're trying to create another page to do that for you.

So, if you follow me, you're doing this the wrong way. What you should do is to create a separate page and assign it as the home page of your blog. It would then free the index.php file for you to use it as the blog list, as it is by default.

Comment: This is the right answer, unfortunately many theme authors are not doing it this way. Right now I'm stuck with a theme (square theme) that changes the index and I have no way of displaying the recent posts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you did it the correct way (as mentioned by Guilherme), you should have a page designated as the blog list page.

The URL for the blog list if using the page 'My Blog' to display posts and pretty links for the url should be something like http://mywebsite.com/my-blog.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
// Default homepage
echo "Default homepage";

} elseif ( is_front_page()){

    echo "Static homepage";
// Static homepage

} elseif ( is_home()){
    echo "Blog page";
// Blog page

} elseif ( is_page( 'cart' ) || is_cart()){
    echo "cart";
// Blog page

}  elseif (is_single()){
    echo "is_single";
// Blog page

} elseif (is_product_category()){
    echo "is_product_category";
} 
 else {
echo "Everything else";
// Everything else
}  ?>
```